# c++ vector clear() doen't work

Tags: c++, stl

```
string str;
vector<int> v(200,0);
getline(cin, str);
for (int i = 0 ; i < str.size(); i++) {
    v[str[i]-97]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    printf("%d ", v[i]);
}

v.clear();
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    printf("%d ", v[i]);
}
```

I want to know the number of each alphabet and clear vector v. But it doesn't work. what is the reason?

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior* by reading from the vector after clearing it

Comment: Why do you use so many magic-numbers?

Comment: "it won't work" isn't a problem description; you should post what is expected, and what you're getting

Comment: If we give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you're using  ASCII, only your last loop is broken, why would you expect a cleared vector to contain anything? You should pretty much never loop up to some hard coded amount of elements

Comment: the result is same before and after v.clear().

Comment: The "result" after `v.clear()` is UB - try changing `v[i]` to `v.at(i)` and see what happens

Comment: I thought after clear, there will be just space by last loop. I will try again. thank you

Comment: I tried it but it crashed with error massage - terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_rage'

Comment: i checked printf("%d", v.empty()) and result is 1. Last loop seems to meaningless

Answer (score 1):

Calling v.clear() resizes the vector to zero elements. If you want to set the elements to a specific value (here 0), keeping the original size, you may use

```
v.assign(v.size(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last for loop to  :

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    printf("%d ", v[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing your vector, removing all elements and then you seem to be trying to loop through it's first 25 elements, even though it's empty.

The reason you're throwing std_out_of_range is because you're trying to access elements where they don't exist.

You should pretty much never loop through something through an already set number of times if you can't ensure that the vector in question won't have that many elements.

If you absolutely have to loop through your vector a set number of times, at least ensure that your vector will have that many elements first.

```
if (v.size() >= 25)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d ", v[i]); 
    }
}
```

In this case your vector will most definitely not have 25 elements since you cleared your vector prior to the loop, but it's much more safe.